# Steam Tf2 Trading BOT Node.js problems

Tags: node.js, steam

Here is my piece of code

```
// Any time an item changes in the trade window
trade.on('offerChanged', function(itemAdded, item) {
if (itemAdded) {
    logger.info('User added: '+item.name)
    if (item.name == 'Festive Black Box') {
        trade.chatMsg('Cool!');
        trade.addItem('Scrap Metal');
    }
}
```

So, basically my brother puts this item in (Festive Black Box), it should put one scrap, but it doesn't, instead saying "Cool!" (so i know it works) and no scrap inserted by the bot, i waited a long time, doesn't seem to work, also I only have one scrap metal in my inventory!

Here are some more pieces of my code;

```
// After we accept the trade, we deal with the trade session
client.on('sessionStart', function(steamID) {
    inTrade = true;
    client.setPersonaState(steam.EPersonaState.Busy);
    trade.open(steamID, function() { // Pass the trade off to our steam-trade library
    trade.loadInventory(appid.TF2, contextid.TF2, function(inv) {
        inventory = inv;
        scrap = inv.filter(function(item) { return item.name == 'Scrap Metal';});
        logger.error(scrap)
            if (!inv) {
                logger.error('Error getting own inventory.  Cancelling trade.');
                client.sendMessage(steamID, 'Could not load my inventory, please contact my creator.');
                trade.cancel(steamID);
            } else {
                logger.debug('Found '+inv.length+' items in my inventory.');
                myBackpack = inv; // Now we can access it globally
                // If you want to put items up in the trade window immediately,
                // here is where you could do it. Instead we're calling a custom function.
                onTradeStart(steamID); // Our custom function
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you logged `item.name`?

Comment: no, i dont know what it really is, maybe 'Scrap Metal'item.name?

Comment: @TomA example please?

Comment: I have been trying to fix this for 2.5 hours... No luck

Comment: logger.info(item.name) - yes?

Comment: logger.info gave me only "Festive Black Box"

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
scrap = inv.filter(function(item) { 
     return item.tags.some(function(element, index, array) {
            return element.internal_name == 'Scrap Metal';
     });
});
```

Comment: Thanks although rather late, i will get back to bots soon

Answer (score -1):

Here we go:

```
// Any time an item changes in the trade window
trade.on('offerChanged', function(itemAdded, item) {
    if (itemAdded) {
        logger.info('User added: '+item.name)
        if (item.name == 'Festive Black Box') {
            trade.chatMsg('Cool!');
            trade.addItem('Scrap Metal');
            logger.info(trade.addItems(scrap));
        }
    }
    //if (itemAdded)
    //    logger.info('User added: '+item.name);
    //else
    //    logger.info('User removed: '+item.name);
});
```